# What is the cause for this odd OR and ternary output [Javascript]

Tags: ternary

Hey so I am having an issue with an OR and ternary operation. I have this code here.

```
console.log(this.state.records)
Before: {
 AllowCheck: "1"
 Checked: "0"
}

const records = this.state.records.map((record) => {
    return {
        ...record,
        Checked: checked || record.AllowCheck === '0' ? '1' : '0',
    }
});

console.log(records)
After: { 
  AllowCheck: "1"
  Checked: "1"
}
```

When you look at the log before the ternary operation, you see that the object has a property called “AllowCheck”. You can see here that it evaluates as a 1 in the record. If you look at the function below, you’ll see a map operation that iterates over a list of records. The variable “checked” comes from a checkbox onChange operation that will evaluate as true in this situation. In the OR operation you can see that “checked” will be true, and the ternary on the right is where the “record.AllowCheck” will evaluated as a 1 from before. The ternary should result in a 0 since “record.AllowCheck” is 1. You’ll see in the after object that Checked is equal to 1. I don't know why it's not equal to two from the "checked" variables, and I really don't understand how it's equal to 1. Am I missing something? Have I been looking at this for too long? Any opinions or answers would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "You can see here that [AllowCheck] evaluates as a 0 in the record" - we don't see that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you're correct. I changed it to a 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> The ternary should result in a 0 since “record.AllowCheck” is 1

Nope. The condition in this ternary operation is not what you think it is (`record.AllowCheck === '0'`). It's actually `checked || record.AllowCheck === '0'` and, since `checked` is truthy, it short-circuits on the first step, evaluates to true overall and that's how the ternary operator evaluates to `'1'`.

See the operator precedence table for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that was possible. Thank you.